# how to hide dependency jars in eclipse's project explorer window

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, eclipse-kepler

Once i use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate the eclipse IDE file and import the project in eclipse, the eclipse shows all the dependency jars in the project explorer window(see image) ..

**How to hide all the dependency jars in project explorer ?**

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't use `eclipse:eclipse` anymore. Use [m2e plugin in Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) and import the appropriate project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import the project via [m2e plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) the results in Eclipse looks like this:

[image]